# Can't install Selenium WebDriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to install Selenium WebDriver with Python on my Mac. I used this command:

```
sudo easy_install selenium
```

After that, I tried the following simple test:

python

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

And I got the following error. What am I doing wrong?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0.b3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 68, in **init**
>       self.service.start() File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0.b3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a selenium driver without any arguments, the path to the webdriver executable must be in the system PATH environment variables.

Alternatively, you can specify the path explicitly as such:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox("path/to/the/FireFoxExecutable")
```

Comment: Thanks! How do find out path/to/the/FireFoxExecutable on my mac?

Comment: this answer tells how to add the browser binary location, not geckodriver's location... so it does not answer the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that it can't find `geckodriver`.  **geckodriver** is an additional component that you must install to control Firefox.  It's not included with the selenium package, so it must be installed separately.

The following shell script will download the latest **geckodriver** from Mozilla's repo and place it in `usr/local/bin`, so it can be found on your PATH:

```
#!/bin/sh
url=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest" | python -c "import sys, json; r = json.load(sys.stdin); print [a for a in r['assets'] if 'linux64' in a['name']][0]['browser_download_url'];")
curl -L -o geckodriver.tar.gz $url
tar -xzf geckodriver.tar.gz
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin
```

(run this script after you install selenium via `pip` or `easy_install`)